# What are the implications of the 64-bit support Apple announcement for Worklight 6.1 developers?

Tags: ios, 64-bit, ibm-mobilefirst

As you're probably aware, Apple announced back in october that since febrary the App Store will only accept iOS apps built with 64-bit architecture support (https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a).

> Starting February 1, 2015, new iOS apps uploaded to the App Store
>   must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK, included
>   in Xcode 6 or later. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend
>   using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to
>   build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code.

As a Worklight 6.1 developer, I would like to know what are the implications of this announcement for my apps. Do I need to make any changes to my source code or config files to support 64-bit architecture?

Thank you,

Alejandro

Comment: Better you ask that question here : http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the following blog post by the IBM Worklight development team specifically addressing this topic: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2014/12/17/ios-64-bit-support/

You will need to download the latest iFix for your version of Worklight and re-build your application in order to add 64 bit support.

Note that for:

- EXISTING applications (already on the market), you have time until June 1st.
- NEW applications (not yet on the market), must contain 64 bit support starting February 1st.

Comment: Does anyone know whether the 64bit support needs to be in the app at the time of submission, or the time of approval? I have some 3rd party libs which  are not updated yet. Could I upload a build on 31st Jan and have a new app approved (which would probably happen around 7th-10th)?

Comment: The February date is only for new apps. June is for app updates.

Comment: Yes this is a new app, but more specifically I'd like to know whether the Feb date refers to the time of submission, or the time of approval/release?

Comment: Don't know. Probably need to read some official sources from Apple, or contact them.